# Mod RewriteRule that matches numbers 1-15

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following 3 rewrite rules to load static cached files if the user is on page 1-15. Is there a way I can combine these, particularly the last 2 into 1 rule? I've been unable to find any way to specify a range of 1-15.

```
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/cache_html/cache_static_popular_results_1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^popular/page:([1-9])$ app/webroot/cache_html/cache_static_popular_results_$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^popular/page:(10|11|12|13|14|15)$ app/webroot/cache_html/cache_static_popular_results_$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can combine these, particularly the last 2 into 1 rule

How about

```
RewriteRule ^popular/page:([1-9]|1[0-5])$ app/webroot/cache_html/cache_static_popular_results_$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Apart from the OP doesn't want to match `popular/page:0` so the single digit range should be `[1-9]` :-)